# How do remove all Unicode from string, BUT keep lanauges such as: Japanese, Greek, Hindi etc

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

How would I remove all Unicode from this string【Hello!】★ ああああ
I need to remove all the "weird" symbols (【, ★, 】) and keep "Hello!" and "ああああ". This needs to work for all languages not just Japanese.

Comment: are weird symbols `【` , `★`, and `】` in this case?  do we need to consider other symbols?

Comment: Yes, other symbols as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove characters within the [Unicode categories](https://regular-expressions.mobi/unicode.html?wlr=1) Other Symbol, Combining Symbol, and Enclosing Mark, but leave those from other categories.

Using regular expressions, those match the classes `\p{So}`, `\p{Sk}` and `\p{Me}`, respectively. You might for example use [`XRegExp.replace()`.](https://regular-expressions.mobi/xregexp.html)

Comment: There is a regular expression with PHP which looks like `\p{common}`, this would work, *but* this is PHP, I need JavaScript. Same goes with yours.

Comment: There are [regex libraries for JavaScript that support categories.](https://regular-expressions.mobi/xregexp.html)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution. Using XRegEXP, I was able to use PHP's `\p{Common}` in node.

```
const xreg = require('xregexp');

let str = '【Hello!】★ ああああ】';
let regex = new xreg('\\p{Common}', 'g');
let res = xreg.replace(str, regex, ' ');

console.log(res); // Hello    ああああ
```

Comment: Side note: PHP borrowed that syntax from PCRE, which stands for Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions. (Its syntax is not really Perl-compatible.)